# Oscar offer app override Benefits functions conflicts error

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, e-commerce, django-oscar

I use Oscar 1.6.4 version. I want to override `PercentageDiscountBenefit` in `oscar.app.offer.benefits.py`. But conflict error happens. How can I override this functions?

```
from oscar.core.loading import get_classes

CorePercentageDiscountBenefit, CoreAbsoluteDiscountBenefit = get_classes('offer.benefits', ['PercentageDiscountBenefit', 'AbsoluteDiscountBenefit'])


class PercentageDiscountBenefit(CorePercentageDiscountBenefit):

    def apply(self, basket, condition, offer, discount_amount=None,
              max_total_discount=None):

        print(
            "\n\n\n\n",
            "PRINT SOMETHING",
            "\n\n\n\n",
        )
        return super().apply(basket, condition, offer, discount_amount,
              max_total_discount)


class AbsoluteDiscountBenefit(CoreAbsoluteDiscountBenefit):

    def apply(self, basket, condition, offer, discount_amount=None,
              max_total_discount=None):

        print(
            "\n\n\n\n",
            "PRINT SOMETHING",
            "\n\n\n\n",
        )
        return super().apply(basket, condition, offer, discount_amount,
              max_total_discount)
```

**Error log**

```
RuntimeError at /basket/

Conflicting 'percentagediscountbenefit' models in application 'offer': <class 'oscar.apps.offer.benefits.PercentageDiscountBenefit'> and <class 'oscar_apps.offer.benefits.PercentageDiscountBenefit'>.

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/basket/
Django Version:     1.11.9
Exception Type:     RuntimeError
Exception Value:    

Conflicting 'percentagediscountbenefit' models in application 'offer': <class 'oscar.apps.offer.benefits.PercentageDiscountBenefit'> and <class 'oscar_apps.offer.benefits.PercentageDiscountBenefit'>.

Exception Location:     /home/seyidov/PycharmProjects/Backend/embahome-backend/.venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py in register_model, line 224
Python Executable:  /home/seyidov/PycharmProjects/Backend/embahome-backend/.venv/bin/python
Python Version:     3.5.2
Python Path:    

['/home/seyidov/PycharmProjects/Backend/embahome-backend',
 '/home/seyidov/PycharmProjects/Backend/embahome-backend',
 '/usr/lib/python35.zip',
 '/usr/lib/python3.5',
 '/usr/lib/python3.5/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload',
 '/home/seyidov/PycharmProjects/Backend/embahome-backend/.venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages',
 '/home/seyidov/Documents/Programs/pycharm-2018.2.4/helpers/pycharm_matplotlib_backend',
 '/home/seyidov/PycharmProjects/Backend/embahome-backend']
```

Comment: Add error log as text instead of image.

Comment: @shaikmoeed I added error logs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't override benefit classes in this way. If you want to create a custom benefit that applies different logic to the core ones, you need to create your own class which is a proxy for the core `Benefit` model:

```
from oscar.apps.offer import models

class CustomPercentageDiscountBenefit(models.Benefit):

    class Meta:
        proxy = True

    def apply(self, basket, condition, offer, discount_amount=None, max_total_discount=None):
        # Apply your benefit here
```

This is explained in [more detail in the documentation](https://django-oscar.readthedocs.io/en/releases-1.6/howto/how_to_create_a_custom_benefit.html).

Comment: Thank you for answer.Also I edited `AbstractBenefit` model. 
`@property
    def proxy_map(self):
        return {
            self.PERCENTAGE: get_class(
                'offer.benefits', 'CustomPercentageDiscountBenefit')
   }`